# QSqlRecords inserted into model are empty/blank in QTableView

Tags: qt, qt5

Problem occurs when inserting a QSqlRecord into a QSqlTableModel via

```
record = self.tablemodel.record()
record.setValue('originfile_path', filepath)
record.setValue('originfile_hash', filehash)
record.setValue('image', img_pkl)
record.setValue('area', area)
self.tablemodel.insertRecord(-1, record)
```

An inserted record shows up in the QTableView as blank record with an exclamation point. It is inserted into the database—closing and reopening the application causes the records to show up normally.

[image: Exclamation Point Records rows]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark you primary key generated to False, in pyqt this is done via:

```
record.setGenerated('tableid', False)
```

A similar problem was happening there due to a complete lack of a Primary Key:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/37023/solved-updating-qsqlrecord-during-qsqltablemodel-beforeupdate-causes-blank-row-in-qtableview/4

The relevant [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setRecord):

**QSqlTableModel::setRecord**

> The caller should remember to set the generated flag to FALSE for fields where the database is meant to supply the value, such as an automatically incremented ID.

The issue is caused by a discrepancy between the SQLite-generated PK and the QT-generated PK.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your edit strategy:

```
tablemodel.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
```